# Email address Input from Form to Table

Tags: php

I am trying to have a form take the input of a username and have the @domain.com automatically added to the table.
My code for the form is:

```
<th>Owner Emaill: *  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />@informatica.com </td></tr>
```

and the table is:

```
echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'">' . $row['email'].'</a></td>';
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what result do you have now?

Comment: do you want to append the domain name?

Comment: echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'@domain.com">' . $row['email'].'</a></td>';

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the domain name to the $row['email'] ?

Comment: @PhpDev I am just getting the username in the table without the domain name

Comment: @Swapper That actually worked Thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it too:

```
echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row['email'].'@informatica.com">' . $row['email'].'@informatica.com</a></td>';
```